# Дерамида с поворотами

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, бинарное-дерево

Дерамида строится как обычное бинарное дерево поиска, но каждому элементу дополнительно приписывается поле приоритета, по которому элементы должны удовлетворять свойству пирамиды. При вставке в дерамиду элемент добавляется в дерево поиска, а потом мы поднимаемся вверх и выполняем повороты (не нарушающие свойства дерева), пока приоритет нарушает свойство пирамиды. В чем я ошибся при реализации этого алгоритма? При отладке попадаем в какой-то файл, связанный со временем, а потом выдается сообщение о нарушении прав доступа. Программа крашится.

```
struct deramid_node{
    int key;
    int priority;
    deramid_node *left;
    deramid_node *right;
    deramid_node *parent;
};

typedef deramid_node deramid;

struct deramid_node * create_tree(void){
    deramid *root;

    root = (deramid *)malloc(sizeof(deramid));
    root->key = NULL;
    root->parent = NULL;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    return root;
}

void left_rotate(deramid *root, deramid *x){
    deramid *y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;
    if(y->left != NULL) y->left->parent = x;
    y->parent = x->parent;
    if(x->parent == NULL) root = y;
    else{
        if(x == x->parent->left)    x->parent->left = y;
        else                        x->parent->right = y;
    }
    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y;
}

void right_rotate(deramid *root, deramid *x){
    deramid *y = x->left;
    x->left = y->right;
    if(y->right != NULL) y->right->parent = x;
    y->parent = x->parent;
    if(x->parent == NULL) root = y;
    else{
        if(x == x->parent->right)   x->parent->right = y;
        else                        x->parent->left = y;
    }
    y->right = x;
    x->parent = y;
}

void deramid_insert(deramid *root, deramid *z){
    deramid *x = root;  //Отмечает проходимый путь
    deramid *y = NULL;  //Ссылается на родительский по отношению к x узел

    //Добавляем элемент по ключу
    srand(time(NULL));
    z->priority = rand() % 701;
    while(x != NULL){
        y = x;
        if(z->key < x->key) x = x->left;
        else                x = x->right;
    }
    z->parent = y;  //все поля z кроме key должны быть NULL
    if(y == NULL) root = z;
    else{
        if(z->key < y->key) y->left = z;
        else                y->right = z;
    }
    z->parent = y;
    //Поднимаемся вверх и выполняем повороты
    while(y != root){
        if(y->priority > y->left->priority) right_rotate(root, y);
        if(y->priority > y->right->priority) left_rotate(root, y);
        y = y->parent;
    }
}
```

Программа работает верно, если закомментировать код, где выполняются повороты. Мне кажется, я принципиально не понял, что надо делать после добавления элемента, но ошибку не вижу. Все соответствует текстовому описанию.

А еще, есть ли какие-то замечания по коду? Как можно улучшить определение типов узлов, которые используются при построении дерева? Как исправить код вставки, который крашится, если в качестве root передается NULL? Думаю, функция должна верно вставлять элемент даже когда дерево пустое (передан NULL), и вставляемый элемент должен стать корнем. Там ниже по коду этот случай и учитывается, то почему-то не работает. Приходится для root создавать узел с нулевыми полями, и из-за этого при обходе выводится лишний элемент.

https://ideone.com/1ZDuxS

Answer (score 1):

Декартово дерево (дерамида) на поворотах? Вы уверены, что не перепутали несколько алгоритмов в одном? Например, AVL- и Splay-деревья живут поворотами, а декартово дерево - разделением и слиянием (Split и Merge).

Повороты не работают на декартовом дереве вообще. Если у вас есть набор пар `(key, priority)`, то они *однозначно* задают дерево, т. е. после поворота вы никогда не получите корректное декартово дерево.

Почему дерево по набору пар строится однозначно? Пусть пирамида приоритетов имеет минимум в корне (с максимумом всё будет то же самое). В качестве корня следует выбрать узел с минимальным приоритетом, так как корень пирамиды всегда минимален.
Далее, относительно этого корня надо по ключу разделить все вершины на те, что слева от корня (ключ меньше) и справа (ключ больше). На получившихся наборах надо рекурсивно продолжить построение.

Таким образом, повороты корректно работают только на декартовом дереве с равными приоритетами, ну а зачем они тогда?

Comment: Нет, уверен. Во-первых, об этой возможности говорится то ли в Кормене, то ли в Седжвике, и к тому же на хабре в статье про декартовы деревья писали, что был тест скорости работы разных деревьев поиска, и там победила дерамида с поворотами.

Comment: @typemoon А можете привести ссылку? Потому что ничего подобного ни в тех книгах, ни в сети я не нашёл. Хотя я только студент, в двоичных деревьях уже достаточно много знаю, и ни я, ни некоторые более глубоко знакомые с Comuter Science не слышали о такой о реализации дерамиды. Единственное подобное -- через "повороты" можно делать разворот любого подотрезка в дерамиде по неявному ключу.

Comment: https://books.google.ru/books?id=UVg1LPacgRcC&pg=PA361&lpg=PA361&dq=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=_U9OMsiYxK&sig=JwInlBNe5rc0avi-rfA9S6bfTrA&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B&f=false

Comment: @typemoon Окей, я действительно нашёл такую тему. Она на взгляд не быстрее (и вроде даже доказано, что медленнее, но только на константу) чем обычная дерамида с Split/Merge. Я вроде понял идею, попробую дать другой ответ, если найду ошибку.

Comment: @typemoon Добавил новый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Весь код про повороты наверное должен работать с `z`, а не с `y`. Что-то похожее на:

```
while (z != root) {
    if(z->parent->priority > z->priority) {
        if (z-parent->left == z)
            right_rotate(root, z->parent);
        else
            left_rotate(root, z->parent);
    }
    z = z->parent;
}
```

Comment: @typemoon Ответ вам помог?